# Empty Arrays and iOS 7 SDK

Tags: arrays, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray, ios7

Just updated my XCode from 4.6 to 5, and along with it the iOS7 SDK.

I noticed that **all operations (e.g. Predicate filters etc) I attempt to perform on empty NSArray or NSMutableArray cause an exception (NSInvalidArgumentException)** when running my app in the simulator for either iOS 5.1 or iOS 7 (still struggling to download iOS 6.1)
My arrays are instantiated (so they are not Nil), but they have 0 entries.

So code that used to work fine in XCode 4.6 now crashes, and I have to add an extra IF to check if the array.count == 0 before running that line of code all over my app. (Monumental task)

When I download my app (version I published with XCode 4.6) from the AppStore to an iOS7 device, it works just fine.

Anyone else also experiencing this?

Comment: No, it all works fine in iOS 7, no monumental reworks required. What kind of operations you're trying to perform and how you instantiate your arrays? Can you give en example of couple code lines which fail? Maybe you send NSMutableArray operations to NSArray or something like this?

Comment: Can you show one of the NSInvalidArgumentExceptions you're seeing?

Comment: Crashes on last line. This code works in XCode 4.6.3. The NSMutableArray stored at [defaults objectForKey:@"Wards"] is NOT Nil.     

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *userData = [defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", UserID]];
NSMutableDictionary *userDictionary = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:userData] mutableCopy];
NSArray *SelectedWards = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"Wards"]];

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSArray initWithArray:range:copyItems:]: array argument is not an NSArray'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on this code, I think the value stored in [defaults objectForKey:@"Wards"] is not an array, please double check the value

```
 NSArray *SelectedWards = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"Wards"]];
```

you may use following code to check

```
if(![[defaults objectForKey:@"Wards"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
     NSLog("OOPs!  Wards is not an array");
}
```

Comment: Embarrassingly, you are correct. Thank you. It seems some temp code of mine stored a NSMutableDictionary into my defaults. Once I reset my simulator's content and settings, it worked. Thank you!